# How to get argument on serverside server callback fivem

Tags: lua, fivem

So i'm very new to lua and I wrote this:

Clientside

```lua
ESX.TriggerServerCallback('mapbuilder:getMoney', function(money)
                    if selectedmatamount == nil or money >= selectedmatamount then
                        TriggerServerEvent('mapbuilder:removeMoney', selectedmatamount)
                        print('' .. material .. '\n')
                        TriggerServerEvent('mapbuilder:syncObject', selectedObject, coords, heading, isFrozen, mySteamID, desc)
                        TriggerServerEvent('mapbuilder:saveToDatabase', selectedObject, coords, heading, isFrozen, desc)
                        DeleteObject(object)
                        object = nil
                    else
                        ShowNotification(Translation[Config.Locale]['not_enough_money'])
                        DeleteObject(object)
                    end
                end, material)
```

The variable Material is specified above and is NOT nil

But when I try to get it serverside:

```lua
ESX.RegisterServerCallback('mapbuilder:getMoney', function(source, cb)
    local xPlayer = ESX.GetPlayerFromId(source)
    local xItem = xPlayer.getInventoryItem(material)

    print(material)

    print(xItem.name .. ' ' .. xItem.count)
    cb(xItem.count)
  
end)
```

It tells me, that material = nil

Please help

Comment: In the client (first) example the `material` variable must be defined outside of your callback function. In the server (second) example it is not. My guess is you should pass the value of `material` to the server callback as a parameter, and then extract it on the server side.

Comment: Or, to put it another way, on the server code - where does the value for `material` come from in the line `local xItem = xPlayer.getInventoryItem(material)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You're simply missing the "**material**" arugment in your `ESX.RegisterServerCallback` :

```lua
ESX.RegisterServerCallback("mapbuilder:getMoney", function(source, cb, material)
  local xPlayer = ESX.GetPlayerFromId(source)
  local xItem = xPlayer.getInventoryItem(material)

  print(material)

  print(xItem.name .. " " .. xItem.count)
  cb(xItem.count)
end)
```

---

The rule is that your variables `source`, `cb`, `var1`, `var2`, ... should be in the same order in the `ESX.RegisterServerCallback` and `ESX.TriggerServerCallback`
The `source` is automatically added
The `cb` is the callback function declared in the client

So a simple example would be :
`server.lua`

```lua
ESX.RegisterServerCallback('myEvent', function(source, cb, var1, var2)
  print(var1, var2)
  local var3 = 3
  local var4 = 4
  cb(var3, var4)
end)
```

`client.lua`

```lua
local var1 = 1
local var2 = 2
ESX.TriggerServerCallback('myEvent', function(var3, var4)
  print(var3, var4)
end, var1, var2)
```

Would print :

1. Server : `1 2`
2. Client : `3 4`